# Function echo location php

Tags: php

i'm pretty new to php and I'm trying to figure out how to display errors to the page.

I have this function made.

```
 function error($errorreason){
  echo("<div id='error1' class='alert text-bold alert-danger'>" . $errorreason . "<span id='error1' class='clickable pull-right'><i class='ion-close-round'></i></span></div> ");
 }
```

And I'll call it when-ever I need to display an error with `error("blah blah");` but the issue I'm having is that it echos the error at the line where the function is called at, which is at the wrong location as it displays the error inside an element and not on the top of the page where the function is located. I want it to display the error at the same location as the function itself is at. What should I do? Should I use a different method?

Comment: What is the purpose of the i tag as it is empty? and can explain clearly what you expect from `error()` function execution?

Comment: @user10089632 That i tag is a icon, that error is something I would use if something went wrong with a form when it got submitted and it would display the error I have in the error() on top of the page, but when I call it it's not calling it at the top of the page, it calls it in the element where that error() line is at.

Comment: I must be missing something or you just call it first of your script that handles the submit. and a word of advice if you mean by something went wrong, a problem of user input mismatch, you better off handling it with JQuery validation as it avoids the delay

Answer (score 1):

Your ***function do a RETURN*** (no a echo) after this you affect $errorreason ***add the param error*** to your function and call by a **ECHO error("error blabla");**

```
    function error($errorreason){
        return ("<div id='error1' class='alert text-bold alert-danger'>" . $errorreason . "<span id='error1' class='clickable pull-right'><i class='ion-close-round'></i></span></div> ");
    }

    $errorreason = "What's the plan?";
    echo error($errorreason);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, you're also **executing** it. Simply call the function when you want to execute it (and subsequently run the `echo`). If you want the output at the top of the page, simply call the function directly after the function declaration. If you're only running the function once, this can be simplified by simply taking the `echo` statement out of the function entirely.